# Getting Location of the User forever in iOS app

Tags: ios, location, voip, background-process, reboot

I have done an iOS app to get location every 10 minutes and to update the location to the server through web service. I have used setKeepAliveTimeout method to do with VOIP configuration. I didn't use any stream. It works well. But when I reboot my mobile. It does not call a particular method after 10 minutes automatically. Only when I reopen the app again, It gets updated.

Here is my code:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
        //call update method
}];
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where do you call `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:`?

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't do this feature with using background mode (turn on "Background modes" and check "Location update" in "Capabilities" in project settings.